# How can i run a powershell script in Azure?

Tags: azure, powershell

I have a powershell script that i run in Powershell ISE on windows that accesses a dabatabase and updates values.
What is the best way in Azure to be able to run this powershell script and call it when ever i need to ?

Answer (score 0):

> What is the best way in Azure to be able to run this powershell script and call it whenever I need to?

- You can use **`Azure Automation`** to run your PowerShell script in Azure.
- Azure Automation allows you to automate difficult, lengthy, problematic, and frequently repeated operations that are prevalent in the cloud and organisation.
- Using the Azure interface, PowerShell, or the Azure CLI, you can automatically build, deploy, monitor, and maintain resources in your Azure environment.

You can create the automation account using [MS-DOCS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/quickstarts/create-azure-automation-account-portal) and create the runbook with PowerShell 5.1 runtime.

Here is my sample script that updates my table in Powershell.

**Script:**

```
$connectionString = "Server=tcp:xxxxx.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=xxxxxx;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=xxx;Password=xxxxxx;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;"
$querystr = "UPDATE userds SET name = 'Dhoni' WHERE ID = 1;"
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ConnectionString $connectionString -Query $querystr -OutputSqlErrors $true
Write-Output "Value updated successfully"
```

**Output:**
[image]

**Portal:**

I checked that same in the portal it is updated successfully in the table.

[image]

Comment: i have tried this , but i seem to be getting an error:   System.Management.Automation.CommandNotFoundException: The term 'Invoke-Sqlcmd' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet.  Even though i have installed the module under Sahred Resources ->Modules ?

Comment: did you need to install some modules ? I also use az account , so would i need to install the az v7.x module ?

Comment: go Automation account ->modules-> add module -> browse from gallery -> search sql server with 5.1 version run time and install the same.

Comment: that worked , i need to install version 5.1 not 7.2

Comment: Bu t i need to use "az account get-access-token --subscription $subscriptionId "  and it says System.Management.Automation.CommandNotFoundException: The term 'az' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,? But if i try to install the AZ from gallery , there are a number oif dependencies and says must install those . Issue is that there are like 40-50 dependencies . So how can i over come the error ?

Comment: You are trying to execute CLI command in PowerShell it wont work. You created runbook in PowerShell.
Use below command 

Get-AzAccessToken   -ResourceUrl  "https://storage.azure.com"    

 to fetch storage account token.

Comment: not sure what the storage.azure.com is ?

Comment: Hi, @Traci You can get the Access token for the database using `Connect-azaccount --subscriptionId "xxxx"`  and  `Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceUrl "https://database.windows.net".`